# ckeditor with lazyloader in javascript

Tags: ckeditor

Hi I am using below script for editor ,yap its working fine lazy loader function ,only  for initial loaded data ,means am limiting the data for only 15 row after that scrolling the renaming data will come but the editor is not working
 properly,am using ck-editor plugin also

```
div#notesdiv
       textarea(name='notes',id='notes_#{studentdata.id}')

          | &#x9;&#x9;&#x9;
      script(type='text/javascript').
              CKEDITOR.replace( 'notes_#{studentdata.id}' );
       | &#x9;&#x9;
```

Comment: Please help me to come out of this  issues